# Irssi Loop Through Users in Channel

Tags: perl, irc, irssi

I am trying to piece together other scripts i have seen to be able to loop through a list of users on the channel.

Here is what i have come up with

```
my $channel = @_;
foreach my $nick ($channel->nicks()) {
    $server->command("msg $chatchannel $nick->{nick}");
}
```

But all i get from that is

> Can't call method "nicks" without a package or object reference at
>   /root/.irssi/scripts/test.pl line 64.

which is referring to

```
$channel->nicks()
```

Am i going about this the wrong way? or should this be working? I have seen many other scripts using $channel->nicks() so i know it must work?

**Edit**

I should also mention that this is already define further up in the code

```
my ($server, $msg, $target, $channel, $chatnet) = @_;
```

But when i try it with that $channel variable i get

> Can't locate object method "nicks" via package
>   "mattigins@mattigins.tmi.twitch.tv" (perhaps you forgot to load
>   "mattigins@mattigins.tmi.twitch.tv"?) at /root/.irssi/scripts/test.pl
>   line 64.

Comment: What is in `$_`? Where are you getting it? Obviously it's not a `Channel` object instance as you're expecting.

Comment: Sorry, yeah it was supposed to be @_ which also does the same thing

Answer (score 2):

Since the left hand side (LHS) of `my $channel = @_;` is a scalar it imposes scalar context on the `@_` array. This means that the length of the array gets assigned to `$channel`. You want to assign with `my ($channel) = @_;` so that the LHS is in list context and that the first element in the `@_` array gets assigned to your scalar.

Ref:

[What is the difference between the scalar and list contexts in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376921/what-is-the-difference-between-the-scalar-and-list-contexts-in-perl)

[Scalar and List context in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802541/scalar-and-list-context-in-perl)

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I tried putting the () around the $channel but now i get this error `Can't locate object method "nicks" via package "Irssi::Irc::Server" at /root/.irssi/scripts/test.pl line 64.`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it.

```
$chan = $server->channel_find('#channel');
foreach my $nick ($chan->nicks()) {
    $nickname = $nick->{nick};
}
```